# Apache2.4 SSL mode doesn't work

Tags: apache, ssl

I just configured an Apache2.4 server to work in SSL mode. I generated the key and Self Signed Cerfificate, edited the `conf/httpd.conf` and `conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` and after uncommenting `Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` from `httpd.conf` file, the server doesn't start. Here is the log file:

```
[Sun Jan 17 18:31:47.122863 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5736:tid 468] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sun Jan 17 18:31:47.122863 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5736:tid 468] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 17 18:31:47.122863 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5736:tid 468] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
[Sun Jan 17 18:31:47.122863 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5736:tid 468] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
[Sun Jan 17 18:31:47.122863 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5736:tid 468] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5832
[Sun Jan 17 18:31:47.715664 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5832:tid 408] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sun Jan 17 18:31:47.731264 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5832:tid 408] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Jan 17 18:49:38.248874 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5736:tid 468] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun Jan 17 18:49:40.249988 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5832:tid 408] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun Jan 17 18:49:40.263989 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5736:tid 468] AH00430: Parent: Child process 5832 exited successfully.
```

Could you tell me what is the problem?

**EDIT:**
Launching `httpd.exe` gives this error:

```
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Comment: Is something else listening on port 443? Do you have dup/overlapping Listen directives?

Comment: Found chrome.exe listening on 443

Comment: you sure not just an established connection _to_ 443?

Comment: Yes, I found another one, killed it and launching `httpd.exe` doesn't give errors any more. When I try to start the service from services it fails.

Comment: Works, finally. Thanks for your help and time.